# How to understand three dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've tried to understand how three dimensional arrays work in Java.
I know the rules two dimensional but I copmletely don't know how to use in practice three dimensional.

```
int[] num1to3 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] num4to6 = {4, 5, 6};
int[] num7to9 = {7, 8, 9};

int[][] num1to6 = {num1to3, num4to6};

int[][][] allNum = {num1to3, num4to6, num7to9}; // it doesn't work
int[][][] allNum = {num1to6[0], num1to6[1], num7to9}; // it doesn't work too
```

Comment: It's just an array of two-dimensional arrays. Try `{num1to6}`.

Comment: I want to learn how to make three-dimensional array using `num1to3`, `num4to6`, `num7to9`.

Comment: Just replace the `num1to6` in my example with the value of it: `{{num1to3, num4to6}, ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no multidimensional arrays in java - just a syntax that looks and functions similarly; in reality they are arrays of arrays, resembling a *tree* structure more than a multidimensional array.

When you declare a three-dimensional array e.g. `int[][][] myArray`, you get actually just a reference variable myArray whos type is int[][][] (thats a type, just like String or Object). The only type assignment compatible with the first dimension is then int[][] and the only type assignment compatible with the second dimension is int[] and the last dimension is int (you see the pattern that just one set of [] is remove from left to right).

In practice:

```
int[] array1d = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[][] array2d = { array1d, { 4, 5, 6} };
int[][][] array3d = { array2d, { { 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

Both references as well as compatible declarations go happily into their appropiate slots. The third line also shows that dimensions need not be of equal size (contrary to classical multidimensional arrays). They don't even need to exist:

```
int[][] array2d_part = { { 1, 2, 3}, null };
```

Thats an array containing an array { 1, 2, 3 } at index 0 and a null at index 1. Since all except the rightmost dimension are reference types, null fits (null is compatible with *any* reference type).

Comment: Thank you, it's much easier to understand for me now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine two dimensional array as matrix, then three dimensional would be a cube, filled with numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I know it but I don't know how to use this knowledge to write correct 3d array. I don't know even if my example above with three arrays which I want to combine to one three-dimensional array is correct.

Comment: If you have something like `array[m][n][k]` then you could imagine it having m two dimensional arrays on one of its axises, n on one of the other and k on the third one.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you initialize a 2D or 3D array while declaring it, you need to setup two parenthesis. For eg

```
int[][] doubleDoug= { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
int[][][] tripleDoug= { {1,2,3,}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
```